# is the jenkinsfile must in root directory, give me tips Jenkinsfile could not be found

Tags: jenkins

Now I am build [my project](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/retire.git) using jenkins pipeline. But now the Jenkinsfile not in my project root path, so I specify the path to `${WORKSPACE}/dolphin-post/Jenkinsfile` in the jenkins configuration dashboard. But now the log tell me could not found the Jenkinsfile, this is my log output:

```
SuccessScan Repository Log
Started
[Sat Sep 19 14:26:03 UTC 2020] Starting branch indexing...
14:26:03 Connecting to https://api.github.com with no credentials, anonymous access
14:26:04 Jenkins-Imposed API Limiter: Current quota for Github API usage has 59 remaining (6 under budget). Next quota of 60 in 59 min
Examining jiangxiaoqiang/retire

  Checking branches...
14:26:04 Jenkins-Imposed API Limiter: Current quota for Github API usage has 59 remaining (6 under budget). Next quota of 60 in 59 min

  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch master
14:26:05 Jenkins-Imposed API Limiter: Current quota for Github API usage has 59 remaining (6 under budget). Next quota of 60 in 59 min

  Getting remote pull requests...
      ‘${WORKSPACE}/dolphin-post/Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Does not meet criteria
14:26:07 Jenkins-Imposed API Limiter: Current quota for Github API usage has 59 remaining (6 under budget). Next quota of 60 in 59 min

  1 branches were processed

  Checking pull-requests...

  0 pull requests were processed

Finished examining jiangxiaoqiang/retire

[Sat Sep 19 14:26:07 UTC 2020] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 3.9 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

what should I do  to make it work? I am also tried to write the Jenkinsfile path like this: `./dolphin-post/Jenkinsfile`, still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository scanning is, as it name suggests, scans your GitHub repository and looks for Jenkinsfile configuration at the path you configured.

So if your Jenkinsfile resides on `dolphin-post/Jenkinsfile`, this is the path you need to configure. The `WORKSPACE` is not needed, since it scans your GitHub repository.